# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de guardar fechas en SQLite?

Tags: java, android, optimización, android-sqlite

Desde hace unos días vengo trabajando en una aplicación en Android, en la cual tengo que almacenar datos en SQLite, datos básicos para un control de usuario.

He estado buscando información al respecto sobre la mejor manera de guardar una fecha en SQLite y la mejor que encontré fue guardarlo como valor numérico `Long`, pero me gustaría conocer la opinión de ustedes, basado en su experiencia.

De esta manera almaceno los datos incluida la fecha

```
public String getInsertLoginOffline(Login loginParams) {
    long idResult = -1
    UseDatabaseHelper useDataBaseHelper = new UseDatabaseHelper(context, "MyDataBase", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = useDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues dbInsert = new ContentValues();
    StringBuilder fecha = new StringBuilder();
    String outSave = null;

    try {
        dbInsert.put("user", loginParams.getUser());
        dbInsert.put("password", loginParams.getPass()); //--hash

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        fecha.append(String.valueOf(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                    .append("-")
                    .append(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)
                    .append("-")
                    .append(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        Date vpstatusdate = formatter.parse(fecha.toString());

        dbInsert.put("datereg", vpstatusdate.getTime());
        dbInsert.put("status", 1);
        idResult = db.insertOrThrow("LOGIN", null, dbInsert);
        if (idResult > -1) {
           outSave = "OK";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        if (useDataBaseHelper != null) {
            useDataBaseHelper.close();
        }
    }
    return outSave;
}
```

Y la manera de leerla sería así de manera resumida:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
long fecReg = login.getFecReg();    
Date outFecReg = new Date(fecReg);
txtFechaReg.setText("Fecha Registro: " + sdf.format(outFecReg));
```

¿Existe alguna otra forma más eficiente?

Answer (score 18):

**[Tipo de datos Fecha (Date) y hora (Time)](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime)**

SQLite no tiene una clase reservada para el almacenamiento de datos de tipo fechas/o hora. En su lugar, las [funciones integradas de fecha y hora](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) de `SQLite` son capaces de almacenar fechas y horas como valores de texto (TEXT), real (REAL) o entero (INTEGER):

- **TEXT** como cadenas ISO8601 `("AAAA-MM-DD HH: MM: SS.sss")`.
- **REAL** como números de día juliano, el número de días desde el mediodía en Greenwich del 24 de noviembre de 4714 A.C. según el calendario gregoriano proléptico.
- **INTEGER** como Tiempo Unix, es el número de segundos desde `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.
  Las aplicaciones pueden elegir para almacenar fechas y horas en cualquiera de estos formatos y libremente convertir entre formatos utilizando las funciones incorporadas en fecha y hora.

Se guarda y se extrae como tipo `TEXT`, `REAL` o `INTEGER` pero al representarla en la `Interfaz de Usuario` se usa la clase `SimpleDateFormat` para darle un formato adecuado a tus necesidades ("dd/MM/yyyy"), en este caso, es lo que comúnmente se realiza.

En realidad la fecha se puede guardar en cualquiera de los 3 tipos pero comentaría estas consideraciones:

- Si es guardada como **INTEGER**, podría ocupar menos espacio dependiendo de la magnitud del valor, pero necesitas asignarle un formato para representarla en la Interfaz de Usuario.
- Si es guardada como **TEXT**, con el formato que deseas ocupa más espacio pero tal vez no tendrias necesidad de convertirla para representarla en la interfaz de usuario.
- Puedes usar **REAL** o **INTEGER** dependiendo si los rangos descritos anteriormente estan dentro de tus necesidades.

Hablando como desarrollador de `Android`, desde mi punto de vista lo mejor es guardarla como tipo **INTEGER**, y en base a un formateador se puede representar de diversas formas en la `UI`.

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE ARTICULOS( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "titulo TEXT, "+
                "fecha INTEGER, "+
                "author TEXT )";
```

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, buena explicación.

Comment: hola @Elenasys yo tengo un error al parsear la fecha me manda este error

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Feb 27 00:00:00 EST 2016" (at offset 0)

Comment: Hugo el formato que intentas introducir no es aceptado. Me parece que el formato oficial usando date-time es yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss